# Controlling Access to .NET Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I have a group of dlls for WCF services. The contain contracts, interfaces etc. I would like to reuse this code in the API (client side) but don't want the consumers of the API to use these features.

Is there a way to say core.dll can only be used by clientcore.dll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can give all the members of `core.dll` an access modifier of `internal` and then use [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to give access to `clientcore.dll`.

To make life easier for your clients, you might actually want to merge `core.dll` into `clientcore.dll` using [ILmerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx). That way your callers don't need to copy a DLL they never use directly.

Comment: We have grouped your dll wil ilmerge. The end API will just be on dll. Thanks for that point.

Comment: @Arnej65: Then making the functionality in core `internal` is all you need to do. You'll need `InternalsVisibleTo` at compile-time, but it won't actually be *used* at execution time as all of your code will be in one assembly.

Comment: As a follow up. I have a public interface that needs an internal object. I have added the VisibleTo condition but the compiler is throwing 'less accessible'. any thoughts?

Comment: @Arnej65: You can't use an internal type within member signatures in a public interface - otherwise you've basically got a member which doesn't make sense to the outside world.

Comment: maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. In the end, i want to take the BO and some interfaces from the service project and re-use the code in the API. I don't want the consumer to use this information. So ... do i make all the Service side internal or can I force just the assembly to only access the 'client' dll as the consumer?

Comment: @Arnej65: It's not entirely clear what you mean, but I suspect you will need to make everything (other than the types you *really* want to expose) internal, yes.

Comment: @JonSkeet let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2170/discussion-between-arnej65-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make your types internal and then use the **friend assembly mechanism** (via the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) class).

Answer (score 0):

sure, it's called:

[Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: If you are looking to using CAS within .NET 4, be sure to [review the changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527276.aspx) from previous versions.  There were some notable ones.